# Back button support using routing in Sencha

Tags: html, cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am newbie to Sencha. Can anyone please explain how to support back button in android using Sencha touch2 Routing. I have gone through Sencha document, they explained there with senarios like "#products/123". But in my case only views get changed not url which is always like "../index.html".

Lets consider i have one login page. On login button tap it navigates to Home page. Now on device back button tap it should navigate back to login. So what format should i put inside route:{}.

Please anyone explain me with simple code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your button actions you should redirect like this:

```
 control: {
        'button[action=login]' : {
            tap: function() {
                this.redirectTo('login');
            }
        }
```

Then add the route in your controller:

```
config: {
    refs: {
        main: 'main'
    },

    routes: {
        'login': 'showLogin'
    }
}
```

and finally in the showDetail function you make the view change, the url should show something like index.html#detail:

```
showLogin: function() {
    this.getMain().push({
        xtype: 'loginView'
    });
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

After doing lot of Google search finally got the answer with proper example. So this is for reference http://thanksmister.com/?p_=336

Answer (score 0):

You can also give yourself better control by defining the Back Button, as well as its references, instead of using the default.

```
Ext.define('Mov.view.BackButton', {
    extend: 'Ext.Button',
    alias: 'widget.backbutton',

    config: {
        hidden: true,
        id: 'back',
        ui: 'back',
        text: 'Back',
        backStack: {

        }
    },

    addToBackStack: function(dispatchOptions) {
        var found = false;
        this.backStack.forEach(function(el) {
            found = found || (Ext.encode(el) == Ext.encode(dispatchOptions));
        });
        if (!found) {
            this.backStack.push(dispatchOptions);
        }
        this.show();
    },

    clearBackStack: function() {
        this.backStack = [];
        this.hide();
    },

    handler: function(button, event) {
        var dispatchOptions = this.backStack.pop();

        Ext.dispatch(dispatchOptions);

        if(this.backStack.length === 0) {
            this.hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Then on your app's navigation bar, you apply this widget. (onInitialize of initial view works well).

```
nav = this.getNavigationBar(),
nav.setBackButton(Ext.widget('backbutton'));
```

@jurodr has a nice example for routing, reference and control, which works well with this custom component.